# how to get "pressed on sides" effect on a leather texture in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to find out how to get "**pressed on sides**" effect as seen the brown leather header in attached picture ( **image on right side** ) . I don't have a very good hand with photoshop layer effects but was experimenting with bevel and emboss style but not much luck. ( I could get some bevel like effect on black nav bar , **image on left side** , but not close to what I want to achieve ).

This is a learning stage for me. Any any help in the right direction would be great!
Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Update#1**:- sample image is taken from dribbble link ( posted by a great designer) : http://dribbble.com/shots/558934-islamic-app

**update#2**: After spending hours the best I could do to is below. Used a combination of gradient layer effect along with white eclipse ( with gaussian blur filter applied) on either sides of the leather to emphasize the lifted leather effect. 
I am not convinced its the best choice of tools in PS. I believe there is a better way to achieve much better and subtle effect like the original sample. Pls feel free to try it out and share your result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a new layer
2. draw a rectangular shape on the area ( any color bg is ok).
3. set the fill to 0% for this layer.
4. add layer style as shown in snapshot below.

Inner glow layer style alone (/w gradient having one end transparent) provides some interesting effect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not too familiar with PS but seems pretty simple. Select the whole leather patch, add a new layer, fill with black. Select that layer and move the selection down, so you can delete the part you don't want black. Increase transparency until it looks correct

Comment: thanks for the idea , I played with for some time got something remotely similar but could not get a nice subtle blend of the slope to the bevel merging with base (as if its the same layer) . ( my output was no where close to the ideal the brown screenshot ;p )

Answer (score 0):

I can walk you through the process if you are still interested. It would require blending modes a bit and bit of layer options. Let me know if you still  need it !